# Android wear app stops receiving notifications after a certain time

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I am using Android Studio 2.1.3, I have made a small application for a Smart Watch that’s used only to receive FCM notifications.
The problem is that every things works pretty good until it stops receiving notification after certain time (one or two hours).

Notifications handler:

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

    intent.setFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP );

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

    notificationBuilder.setContentTitle("FCM NOTIFICATION");
    notificationBuilder.setContentText(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
    notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

Notifications sent from PHP:

```
{"collapse_key":"1734793905","delay_while_idle":false,"to":"__TOKEN__","priority":"high","time_to_live":83,"notification":{"title":"__MSG_TITLE__ ","body":"__MSG_BODY__","sound":true}}
```

Google Firebase response (The same when the notification does not appears on the Smart Watch):

```
{"multicast_id":76761069655130575608,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1478608765404313%e0e2d11fe0e2d89f"}]}
```

I really appreciate any help you can provide.